# Gallery on opening in Android mobile using CameraSource.Photos ionic capacitor

Tags: ionic-framework, plugins, camera, gallery, capacitor

Following code open gallery in web browser (pwa) and works fine  but running the same on android device it is not opening the image gallery .Please let me know if i m missing something .

```
import { Camera, CameraResultType, CameraSource } from '@capacitor/camera';


   async openCamera(){
    
    if (this.imagesend.length <= 1) {
    
    const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
        quality: 90,
        allowEditing: false,
        correctOrientation: true,
        resultType: CameraResultType.Base64, 
              
       source: CameraSource.Photos
      
        
      });
  this.imagesend.push(image.base64String);
  this.base64Image.push("data:image/jpeg;base64," + image.base64String);
}
else{
  let msg = "You can only upload two images.";
      this.presentErrorToast(msg); 
}
}
```

Comment: on the Android device are you still testing the web version or the native version?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I just forgot to add permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The capacitor camera API requires the following permissions be added to your **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

You need to rebuild the app to see the changes in action. You can do this by running the following command:

```
ionic capacitor build android
```

Then run it again using:

```
ionic capacitor run android
```